# myInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() not equals to myType but myInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName equals to myType.FullName

Tags: c#, generics

I'm looking for all implementations of IHandle<> in my assembly.

```
public interface IHandle<T> where T : class, IEvent, new()
```

Those classes looks like

```
public class IHandleEventX : IHandle<EventX>{...}

public class IHandleAnotherEvent : IHandle<AnotherEvent>{...}
```

Currently, I got the following code.

```
aLoader.LoadImplementationOf(typeof(IHandle<>));

// my aLoader class method
public void LoadImplementationOf(Type genericInterface)
{
    // theres another foreach here, to iterate over all assemblies
    foreach (Type aType in allMyAssemblies.GetTypes())
    {
        var interfaces = aType.GetInterfaces();
        foreach (var currentInterface in interfaces)
        {
            if (!currentInterface.IsGenericType) { continue; }
            // the statement below always return false
            if (currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericInterface)
            {}

            // those two statement (FullName and AssemblyQualifiedName), works as expected
            if (currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName == genericInterface.FullName)
            {}
            if (currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition().AssemblyQualifiedName == genericInterface.AssemblyQualifiedName)
            {}

            // those below also fail
            if (currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition().IsAssignableFrom(genericInterface))
            {}
            if (genericInterface.IsAssignableFrom(currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))
            {}
            // can't do currentInterface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() is genericInterface compiler error
        }
    }
```

Why comparing types fail, but comparing types fullname property works ?
Also, whats the best way to do this?

Edit: I rewrote the sample, using only one assembly and IsAssignableFrom worked. I'll investigate and update here later to see why isn't working using more than one assembly - as @HansPassant pointed out

---

It's working now, but I'm not sure why...
I was working with 3 assemblies.

- Asm Loader, there was only de ALoader class there
- Asm Domain, with interfaces IHandle<>, IEvent<> and classes IHandleEventX, IHandleAnotherEvent
- Asm Test, my test project, I was calling aLoader.LoadImplementationOf(typeof(IHandle<>)); from here.

Projects References.

- Loader doesnt references any project.
- Domain references Loader (there was another IInterface on Loader, implemented on Domain)
- Test references both Loader and Domain.

So I moved my interfaces IHandle<> and IEvent<> from Domain to Loader and removed the reference from Domain to Loader, now, its works.

Its still not clear why the IsAssignableFrom failed when IHandle<> was in the domain. It only worked when my IHandle<> and ALoader are in the same assembly.

---

Well, in the end, that was my fault, I was loading de assembly in two load contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because Type.FullName doesn't fully describe a type.  You only get the namespace name and the type name.  But .NET also includes the properties of the *assembly* in which the type resides into the type identity.  Display name, [AssemblyVersion], Culture, PublicKeyToken and (indirectly) ProcessorArchitecture.  You want to compare `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` instead.

The diagnostic for failure like this is that the source code that contains the interface definition is getting compiled into multiple assemblies.  Which in itself is almost always a mistake, you want to make sure that such an interface type only exists in *one* assembly.  And any assembly that uses the interface type has a reference to it so they all use an identical type.

The rules for type identity were loosened somewhat in .NET 4, a type can be identical if it has the same GUID.  The underlying core for the Embed Interop Types feature.  But that only applies to [ComImport] types, I doubt that's the case here.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's about *reference* comparison, considering that `Type` is a reference type.

Use:

[Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

Good luck.

Comment: Edited with your suggestion, didn't worked either. But I see why comparing references will fail, but still didnt found a good way to do this

Comment: -1: Bogus code. Please remove `is` if that was unintentional :)

Comment: @RafaelMueller: strange, did you use IsAssignableFrom(..) ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with IsAssignableFrom. FullNames are the same, I'll post all code, just a minute

Comment: @RafaelMueller: so, are you sure the type you dealing with are actually assignable ? Could be that they are from different assemblies or namespaces, or something like that ?